# phpExcell generating extra worksheets

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpexcel

I'm trying to use phpExell in my Zend application to print out a Excel file with multiple work sheets.

In my controller class I have the following global variable...

```
public $objPHPExcel;
```

which is initialized in an action function like so...

```
$this->objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
```

The action then iterates through some database calls, building a report. On each iteration, it calls the following function, passing in the index of the worksheet as an integer, an array of data to be printed out, and a string containing the name of the worksheet.

```
protected function buildWorksheet($index, $report, $repName) {
   //build new worksheet after default
   if($index > 0) {
       $objWorksheet = $this->objPHPExcel->createSheet();
       $this->objPHPExcel->addSheet($objWorksheet);
   }  else {
        $this->objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($index);
        $objWorksheet = $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
   }  
    //write the worksheet
    $col = 0;
    $row = 1;
    foreach($report as $entry) {
        foreach($entry as $key => $value) {
             $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
            $col++;
        }
        $row++;
        $col = 0;

    }

    $objWorksheet->setTitle($repName);  
}
```

Then, back in the action I print out the excel file...

```
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    ob_start();
    if ( headers_sent() ) die("**Error: headers sent");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="simple.xls"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    ob_clean();
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit();
```

When I open the file in Excel, I get the following message...

```
 Excel found unreadable content in 'simple.xls'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?
```

I click yes. Then get two "Renamed invalid sheet name.' repair error messages. The file contains a worksheet for each iteration, but for everyone after the default sheet, it adds an extra sheet.  Why is it creating the extra spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Create sheet __and add it to this workbook__
 *
 * @param int|null $iSheetIndex Index where sheet should go (0,1,..., or null for last)
 * @return PHPExcel_Worksheet
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function createSheet($iSheetIndex = null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you don't need the call to addSheet. createSheet() automatically does this for you.
 I removed

```
 $this->objPHPExcel->addSheet($objWorksheet);
```

and it works fine now.